# Gridview with SQL data source is removing white spaces

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` connected to my database through an sql data source. It is bound by the follow code:

```
    firstview = "SELECT ID, DC, DD, CYM, CB, ST FROM SCH_SCHEMANAME.TABLENAME WHERE CI = " & txtboxvalue.text & " AND ST = 'whatever' AND D = 0"
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = firstview
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

There is no problem connecting to the database. Inside the database, one of the column contains extra whitespace. To make a long story short, the `DD` column is a short sentence that contains more than one space between some words. e.g. `"This_is____a_sentence_stored___in_the_____dd_column"` where each underscore is a space in this example.

When I do the databind, the spaces in between the words are all reduced to 1 space. I do, however, need to keep the exact amount of spaces between each word when the data is bound in the `GridView`. At the moment, it is showing in the `GridView` as `"This_is_a_sentence_stored_in_the_dd_column"` but I want to keep the amount of spaces rather than have them automatically cut down.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924058/asp-net-binding-to-gridview-strips-some-space-whitespace-characters as well as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767091/grid-view-truncate-multiple-spaces-works-fine-in-textbox?lq=1

Comment: Not related, but you should be using [parameterised queries](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Is this Winforms, ASP, WPF, Etc?

Comment: ASP.NET with VB. I am using AutoGenerateColumns as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix by doing the following on the RowDataBound event for the gridview.

```
e.Row.Cells(4).Text = e.Row.Cells(4).Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
```

The database was retrieving the correct value, but the spaces were being parsed/encoded. JPW's links helped me with the line of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not about a database. The browser treats multiple spaces as one. E.g. see several workarounds here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30740/Avoid-Multiple-Space-Elimination-in-ASP-NET-GridVi